# .htaccess & 301: Redirect URL with capital letters to same URL but in lowercase

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, friendly-url

1) I got mysite.com/about-me.php.

When I type in mysite.com/About-me.php I get a 404 error.
I'd like to add some magic to my .htaccess so that `mysite.com/My-PaGe.php (etc) redirects the user by 301, OR rewrites the URL (whatever is the best?) to mysite.com/my-page.php.`

- Is 301 or rewrite the best?

2) Is is possibly for me to add one rule that applies to all URL's, or do I have to manually specify all different pages?

Bonus 3) Extra bonus star if anybody knows how to rewrite mysite.com/mY-paGe.php to mysite.com/my-site

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This does a 301 redirect, all urls that have an uppercase letter get rewritten to a lowercase version:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

See also this article, in particular the comments section.
http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

You *may* need to specify this line in httpd.conf, and the RewriteCond / RewriteRule in .htaccess

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Comment: @duncan ..and?? How it supposed to work if you have no RewriteMap declaration? This rule on it's own does nothing useful.

Comment: Good point, I'd forgot the map.  Updated my answer to include it.

Comment: @duncan Well .. the problem still "kind of" remains -- RewriteMap **cannot** be declared in .htaccess. At least make a note about this unfortunate moment (it would be so much easier if it would work just like that).

Comment: @LazyOne, I've got a RewriteMap declared in mine exactly like this, I'm not sure I know what you mean. See also an example like http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: ok, I see some people saying the RewriteMap had to be done in a separate httpd.conf file.  I've not needed to do that, but I updated my answer to mention it as a possibility.

Comment: @duncan http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap  ...plus your own link -- read the comments, especially #6 **RewriteMap cannot be declared in .htaccess** -- it will give you an 500 error

Comment: I'm using .htaccess on IIS with Helicontech's ISAPI_Rewrite.  That may be the difference, although I don't see where the Apache docs state RewriteMap has to be declared in httpd.conf.  Whatever, I think the answer more than comprehensively covers both situations.

Comment: @duncan Yeah, in ISAPI_Rewrite it works **completely** different. RE: Apache manual -- it says right there: _"Context: server config, virtual host"_ -- no .htaccess in a list. I consider this resolved as well :)